# Javascript pattern matching

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a string if we know a start point .how to find the end string using js or jquery

```
   var helper="$var_1__ee$var_2__ee";

    $var is the starting point and the end string pattern is ee

  How to split the string based on this pattern
```

Comment: it's raining string patterns today. With more or less the same problem. ;)

Comment: Is this just an example or do you really just want these?

Comment: I want those patterns to be inserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions will be useful here

```
helper.match(/$var[^$]*ee/)
```

To provide a more detailed answer you need to tell us what are you trying to extract from this string.

Comment: The matched string should be replaced with $glob__l__ee

Comment: I still don't have a clear picture of what you're trying to do, but this might be useful `helper.replace(/$var[^$]*ee/, "$glob__l__ee")`